# jquery mark first link as active in menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

What am I trying to do is marking first link in menu as active, or better said, I need it to have a specific css settings. It would be kind of easy to do for me if I would not be using jquery for adding those css settings to the every link when I click on it (simple menu = when you click, it changes color, ...). So I need first link marked in css (as you can see in the code...) and when I click other menu link, the first link gets to normal css settings. Here is my code, I welcome any suggestions.

EDIT: btw, first link is also marked with rel="sl1" ...if it can be useful for solution...

```
 $(document).ready(function()
                {

                    //prvy odkaz musi byt uz oznaceny pri nacitani stranky
                    $('#menu-vertikal li:first-of-type').addClass('aktivny-link');
                      $('#menu-vertikal li a').click(function () {
                      $('#menu-vertikal li.aktivny-link').removeClass('aktivny-link');
                      $('#menu-vertikal li').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('aktivny-link');

                    }); 



                    //zaciatok prepinania obsahu

                    $('#menu-vertikal ul a').on('click', function(){
                           var target = $(this).attr('rel');
                           $("#"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
                        });
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a block of css with properties of your choice for the active menu, then use jQuery `.addClass` to apply it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('li:first-of-type').addClass('current');
  $('li a').click(function() {
    $('li.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.content:visible').hide();
    $('.content').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();
    $('li').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('current');

  });

});
```

```css
.current a {
  color: green;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: calibri;
  text-align: center;
}
.content:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="content">Content one</div>
<div class="content">Content two</div>
<div class="content">Content three</div>
<div class="content">Content four</div>
```

**Note:** I suggest `.addClass` because it adds a predefined class rather than adding inline css like `.css` does and that's not advisable when you're adding a lot of properties.

Comment: never mind, I found problem....my class was mixed with id in links and content divs, .... thanks a lot man! thumb up

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding something like this before the above code.

```
$("#menu-vertikal ul:first-child a").css({
    // specific css settings for first a link
});
```

Comment: this would mark it with css properties as I want with a little change because this exactly doesnt work, but same thing as with Sleek Geek answer, switching between contents doesnt work ...